# Why do characters only move in 4/8 directions in top games?

Tags: 2d, game-design, movement, direction

In many top down games, like Zelda (4 directions)
[image]
There are only 4 or 8 possible directions.

Why is this? Is it a design choice or a technology limitation? I can't think of any reason that even older hardware couldn't handle 360 degree movement.

If it is a technology limitation, then what is limiting it?

But mainly, why is this such a popular design choice? What are some pros and cons to this limited movement style instead of granting freedom to move in any direction?

Comment: Most old games would run on a console with digital input for directions

Comment: @tkausl good thought and answers that part of the question. Still curious why many modern games still follow that control scheme

Comment: Nintendo controllers had a + pad. Four directions. By extension, there could be 8 more. Plus the games were tiles. again, 8 directions. Not sure there is anything else to say about this... And now when you play there is _still_ only 4 arrows on a keyboard. The same issue.

Comment: (not 8 more, but 4 more, for a total of 8)

Comment: The real reason, is because it was a design decision.  That is it.